# is N~N-{1,2,3...n|n is in N}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

so i figured this was a special case of the proof of the compliment of a countable set X and finite subset A is countable

so i start by assuming that N-{1,2,3...n} is finite.
then N-{1,2,3...n}U{1,2,3...n}=N
but i have expressed N as the union of 2 finite sets and that would mean N is finite, which is a contradiction, so N-{1,2,3...n} must be infinite...  but how to i prove it is countable? i was thinking since N-{1,2,3...n} is a subset of N it must be countable... am i on the right track?

Comment: yes you are, a infinite subset $A$ of a countable set $X$ is always countable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your definition of countable? Your statement can be proven directly. A set $S$ is countable if you can find an injective function from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Can you think of a way to map every number that is bigger then some n (with n fixed) to a natural number without mapping two numbers to the same natural number?